# MySQL JOIN select all

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables:

**BOOK**

```
book_id | book_name | book_photo
```

**RUBRIC**

```
rubric_id | rubric_name
```

**AUTHOR**

```
author_id | first_name | last_name
```

**BOOK_RUBRIK**

```
book_id | rubric_id
```

**BOOK_AUTHOR**

```
book_id | author_id
```

I want to select using JOIN like this:

```
SELECT 
  book.book_name, 
  autor.first_name, 
  autor.last_name, 
  rubric_rubric_name 
FROM book 
  INNER JOIN book_autor ON book.book_id = autor_id 
  LEFT JOIN book_rubric ON book.book_rubric = rubric_id 
ORDER BY book.book_id;
```

But it not work. How to select book_name, rubric_name, first_name and_last_name?

Comment: Please try my script and tell me if it is ok. 10x in advance.

Comment: Please @Nevada if you solve your problem approve propper answer.

Answer (score 1):

You missed one table `authors`, so you can not extract data about the author:

```
SELECT 
  book.book_name, 
  autor.first_name, 
  autor.last_name, 
  rubric_rubric_name 
FROM book 
  INNER JOIN book_autor ON book.book_id = book_autor.book_id 
  INNER JOIN author ON book_autor.autor_id = autor.autor_id 
  LEFT JOIN book_rubric ON book.book_rubric = rubric_id 
ORDER BY book.book_id;
```

Adding `INNER JOIN book_autor ON book.book_id = book_autor.book_id` and 
`INNER JOIN author ON book_autor.autor_id = autor.autor_id` instead of `INNER JOIN book_autor ON book.book_id = autor_id` will fix the issue.

**EDIT:**

I missed fact that there are a few errors in the names in the authors script. I fix the select. Here is the propper one:

**YOUR TABLE STRUCTURE:**

```
BOOK
  book_id 
  book_name 
  book_photo

RUBRIC
  rubric_id 
  rubric_name

AUTHOR
  author_id 
  first_name 
  last_name

BOOK_RUBRIK
  book_id 
  rubric_id

BOOK_AUTHOR
  book_id 
  author_id
```

**YOUR SELECT STATEMENT:**

```
SELECT 
  b.book_name, 
  a.first_name, 
  a.last_name, 
  br.rubric_name 
FROM 
  BOOK AS b 
  INNER JOIN BOOK_AUTHOR ba ON b.book_id = ba.book_id 
  INNER JOIN AUTHOR a ON ba.author_id = a.author_id 
  LEFT JOIN BOOK_RUBRIK br ON b.book_id = br.book_id 
ORDER BY 
  b.book_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select book.book_name, author.first_name, author.last_name, rubric.ruburic_name
from book
    inner join book_author on book.book_id = book_author.book_id
    inner join author on book_author.author_id = author.author_id
    inner join book_rubric on book.book_id = book_rubric.rubric_id
    inner join rubric on book_rubric.rubric_id = rubric.rubric_id
order by book.book_id
```

Comment: I think that this is not correct `book_rubric.rubric.rubric_id`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: Check authors schema and made query following it. There are several typos in the script.